# Why do my speakers get distorted randomly on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, firewire

I have a studio monitor setup. I have 2 KRK 6's and a Focusrite Firewire Pro 24.

Every few hours my speakers sound distorted and my solution has been go to sound levels > Properties of Saffire Audio Device > Advanced > Default Format > Toggle to 16 bit then back to 24bit.

Why does it screw up every few hours? Sometimes one speaker doesn't output too and this same process resets it but that's more rare. Is this a OS issue or Focusrite Driver Issue?

Comment: Can you try **Disable all sound effects** in **Speaker Properties** -> **Enhancements**

Comment: I'd say Focusite because every Windows user would be complaining if their OS did that

Comment: Are you trying to play any midi audio at the same time? Most of the time these issues are caused by driver's not being up to date. Or change the buffer size.

Comment: Can you also confirm if distortion occurs on playback (eg, playing a song in your DAW) or from a DI (eg, your guitar plugged in and playing live)

Comment: I don't have an option for Speaker Properties -> Enhancements on the Focusrite. I am not trying to play any midi audio at the same time @ekaj.

Comment: @DaveRook I don't have anything to plug in. I really just have my monitors hooked up to the soundcard to my computer....